# When I am deploying salesforce apex class it is showing error

Tags: apex, unit-test, deployment

I am trying to deploy the apex classes in my target org through force IDE but it showing error, Can you please suggest me where I am doing wrong Deploying showing error log :

> StaticBusinessLogic.testUpdateSearchCreateTaskWhenReferralPlaced
>   System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Email, Phone, Title and Role
>   are Mandatory: [] UpdateLeadTriggerTest.testLeadandTrigger
>   System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Email, Phone, Title and Role
>   are Mandatory: [] ContactIsPortalUser Test coverage of selected Apex
>   Trigger is 0%, at least 1% test coverage is required AddHistory Test
>   coverage of selected Apex Trigger is 0%, at least 1% test coverage is
>   required Average test coverage across all Apex Classes and Triggers is
>   69%, at least 75% test coverage is required.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that one or more of your unit tests are failing, most likely because your production org contains a validation rule (`FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION`) that is not present in your sandbox, or which was introduced after the last time your org's unit tests were run.

You need to ensure that your code is developed to work correctly in an environment that matches your production org. You may need to evaluate performing a sandbox refresh or moving updated metadata components from production into your sandbox. Then, you'd need to run your unit tests, troubleshoot failures (here, by populating the fields required by the validation rule), and re-attempt the deployment.

Alternately, if the classes shown failing here are *not* the classes you're trying to deploy, you need to fix the issue, but may be able to continue your deployment by selecting to Run Specified Tests and execute only the unit tests for the classes you are deploying. However, that does *not* obviate the need to fix the issues in your org.

You also have code coverage issues, with a low mark of 69% coverage. This is certainly influenced by the test failures you see here, but suggests your org as a whole likely needs work on your unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

Add email, phone, title and Role while inserting the data or deactivate the custom validation rule but it is not a best practice.